# Google Chrome Extension Style Popup, not just the content of the popup?

Tags: coding-style, popup, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to style a google chrome extension popup, not just the content of it. I mean the arrow that points to the icon, and the borders, background, etc.

Comment: Popup pages are HTML files, so yes, they're stylable with CSS. If that's what you're asking...?

Comment: You can use `"options_ui":{ "page": "html/popup.html", "chrome_style": true}`, but then your popup is the same as the options page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, those elements are not customizable.